# Swift get the true date

Tags: ios, swift

I have a game and want to reward the user for going on every day. I want to be able to get the true date somehow. I do not want the device date, because the user could just change it and get free rewards. Is there a way for me to access the true date from apple time or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of client libraries that you could use to call out to an NTP server and get the date over a network connection. I've not used either of these, but two that I quickly found are:

- https://github.com/lyft/Kronos
- https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift

You'll need to likely define your own NTP service endpoint, but could easily use `pool.ntp.org`. The Kronos library appears to default to using `time.apple.com`.

Both look relatively easy to use and implement, with examples in the each of the project README.